# How to animate properly in a <canvas>?

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

So I want to recreate this simple animation effect, which uses a <canavs> :

https://codepen.io/w3devcampus/pen/PpLLKY

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Draw a monster in a canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas"  width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function mainLoop() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

  drawMyMonster(xMonster, yMonster);

  xMonster += monsterSpeed;

   if (((xMonster + 100)> w) || (xMonster < 0))  {
    monsterSpeed = -monsterSpeed;
  }

}

function drawMyMonster(x, y) {

    ctx.save();

    ctx.translate(x, y);

    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 10, 10);
    ctx.fillRect(65, 20, 10, 10);
    ctx.strokeRect(45, 40, 10, 40);
    ctx.strokeRect(35, 84, 30, 10);
    ctx.fillRect(38, 84, 10, 10);
    ctx.fillRect(52, 84, 10, 10);

   ctx.restore();
}
```

So, I did recreate it, but it wouldn't behave normally. Instead of displaying one frame at a time, it stacks all the frames up each other in the canvas. Here's my version:

https://codepen.io/Undefined_Variable/pen/LraLJQ

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CanvasThingy</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="CanvasForMonster">
      No support for you scrub!
    </canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myCanvas, context, w, h;

var xMonster = 60;
var yMonster = 30;
var monsterSpeed = 1;

window.onload = function initial(){

  myCanvas = document.body.querySelector('#CanvasForMonster');
  w = myCanvas.style.width;
  h = myCanvas.style.height;
  context = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

ClearCanvas();
}

function ClearCanvas(){
  context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

   DrawFMLface(xMonster, yMonster);

    xMonster += monsterSpeed;

  if(((xMonster + 175) > 299) || (xMonster < 0) ){
    monsterSpeed = -monsterSpeed;
 }

   requestAnimationFrame(ClearCanvas);

}

function DrawFMLface(x, y){
  context.save();

  context.translate(x, y);

  context.strokeRect(0, 4, 175, 80);
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';

  context.fillRect(40, 10, 20, 20);
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';

  context.fillRect(110, 10, 20, 20);
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';

  context.strokeRect(85, 40, 1, 15);
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';

  context.strokeRect(42, 70, 90, 0);
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';

  context.restore();
}
```

Please tell me how to do this properly without jQuery AT ALL, please. I'm still learning and I don't want any jQuery/Angular/React etc. in my code, please!

Comment: You could actually do that particular animation with HTML and CSS only. Would a solution with that approach be acceptable?

Comment: Yes I know but I want to learn how to do it thorough JavaScript. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the previous faces are not being cleared. The clearing is supposed to be done with this line:

```js
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
```

The problem is that `w` and `h` are not set correctly when this is run, so not enough of the canvas is cleared.

This is where you set `w` and `h`:

```js
w = myCanvas.style.width;
h = myCanvas.style.height;
```

This will only work if the width and height were set with CSS, e.g. with an HTML attribute `style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"`, and if you called [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert the CSS style strings into numbers. But in fact the [canvas element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas)’s width and height were set with [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#attr-width) and [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#attr-height) HTML attributes directly. So you should set `w` and `h` with [`HTMLCanvasElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement)’s [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/width) and [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/height) properties:

```js
w = canvas.width;
h = canvas.height;
```

The original Codepen sets them this way.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you were looking for a possibly easier way to do this, you can actually avoid JavaScript entirely when creating a simple animation like this by [using CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations):

```css
#CanvasForMonster {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#Monster {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  animation: bounce 2s alternate linear infinite;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  from { left: 0; }
  to { left: 50%; }
}

#Monster div {
  position: absolute;
}

#Monster .stroke {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#Monster .fill {
  background-color: #000;
}

#Monster .head {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#Monster .eye {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
}

#Monster .eye-left {
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
}

#Monster .eye-right {
  left: 65%;
  top: 25%;
}

#Monster .nose {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 10%;
}

#Monster .mouth {
  left: 25%;
  top: 75%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="CanvasForMonster">
  <div id="Monster">
    <div class="stroke head"></div>
    <div class="fill eye eye-left"></div>
    <div class="fill eye eye-right"></div>
    <div class="stroke nose"></div>
    <div class="stroke mouth"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Everything you have is alright.

The problem is your Globals.

The width of the canvas should be set to:

```
w = myCanvas.width;
```

Height set to:

```
h = myCanvas.height;
```

You have both set as:

```
w = myCanvas.style.width;
h = myCanvas.style.height;
```

Which will not work.

Here is the [fork](https://codepen.io/vinnywoo/pen/MXxEQL) (Demo).

I would highly recommend using JQuery when working with canvas.
When using canvas it should be noted that you want too reference canvas.height, and canvas.width as much as possible rather then using a global that points at the height, and width of the css style.